# Why text in highchart doesn't place in a correct position?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, highcharts

I have used highchart dll in my web app and created charts in c# code instead of javascript.my problem is shown in below pic (texts move to the left and they aren't in correct place), how can i solve it?

```
  Highcharts charts = new Highcharts("chart");
charts.InitChart(new Chart { DefaultSeriesType = ChartTypes.Pie})
                        .SetPlotOptions(new PlotOptions
                        {
                            Pie = new PlotOptionsPie
                            {
                                ShowInLegend = true,
                                AllowPointSelect = true,
                                DataLabels = new PlotOptionsPieDataLabels
                                {
                                    Enabled = true,
                                    Formatter = "function() { return this.point.name +' : '+  this.percentage.toFixed(2)+' %'; }"

                                }
                            }
                        })
                          .SetTooltip(new Tooltip
                          {
                              Enabled = true,
                              Formatter = @"function(){return '<b>'+this.series.name +'</b> <br/>'+this.point.name + ' : ' +  this.percentage.toFixed(2)+' % '; }"
                          })
                          .SetLegend(new Legend
                          {
                              Align = HorizontalAligns.Center,
                              VerticalAlign = VerticalAligns.Bottom,
                              Layout = Layouts.Horizontal,
                              BorderWidth = 0                                      
                         });
             charts.SetTitle(new Title { Text = chartTitleV + " بر اساس " + chartTitleH.TrimEnd(',').ToString() })
            .SetXAxis(new XAxis { Categories = HorCategory })
            .SetYAxis(new YAxis { Title = new YAxisTitle { Text = chartTitleV } })
            .SetSeries(new[]
                    {
                        new Series {Name =  chartTitleH.TrimEnd(',').ToString(), Data = new Data(Results )}
                            });
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try to set [useHTML](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.useHTML) as true in tooltip options.

Answer (score 0):

Do not see the HTML code of the page, but I think that the problem can be in setting the 'dir' property of html elements... As I see the text is written in Arabic language, so the dir="rtl" should be set.

Answer (score 0):

I change direction for div

`<div dir="ltr"  id="chart2" style="height: 300px"></div>`